# Laravel 6.x new password.confirm middleware doesn't work with custom guard

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, guard, password-confirmation

a new password.confirm feature has been added to the laravel 6.2 framework.
I have a fresh laravel 6.18.8 installation, I have done multi-authentication based on guard.
I want to run password.confirm for this custom guard.
Login / logout for guard:admin works correctly, after login redirects to admin/home url correctly. Verification if I am logged in to guard:admin is working correctly so far:
- if I'm already logged in to guard:admin an attempt to enter admin/login redirects me to admin/home - correctly
- if I'm not logged in, the attempt to enter admin/home will redirect me to admin/login - correctly

but

trying to go to admin/secret (which should ask for admin password) redirecting me to user login page because to open password/confirm url (for defualt guard)

When I am logged as admin and manually try to open url admin/password/confirm shows error

```
Target class [admin] does not exist.
```

Is there any chance to run this? Or is made "as is" and won't play with none default auth guard?

Currently my code for guard:admin:
**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
```

**routes/web.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes for admin panel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|
*/

Route::prefix( env('ADMIN_PREFIX', 'admin') )->name('admin.')->namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
    // Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'verify' => false]);
    // Login/out process
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    // Password reset process
    Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('/password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');
    // Password confirmation process
    Route::get('/password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm')->name('password.confirm');
    Route::post('/password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm')->name('password.confirm');

    Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function() {
        Route::view('/home', 'admin.home')->name('home');
        Route::view('/secret', 'admin.secret')->name('secret')->middleware('password.confirm');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see that you can specify where to forward, e.g.

```
middleware('password.confirm:admin.password.confirm')
```

And I found a problem ... stupid me ;P In the constructor of the Admin/Auth/ConfirmPasswordController.php file, I typed middleware('admin:auth') instead of 'auth:admin'

Answer (score 0):

Routes of Web are in routes/web.php and Routes of Admin are in routes/Admin.php

if I add `(->middleware(password.confirm))` in any of the web.php `Routes =>` it works done, and if I add `(->middleware(password.confirm))` in any of the Admin.php `Routes =>` it works done, but

if I add in both just a admin.php Routes works correctly, and in web.php routes, the middleware automatically redirect back